# Can I use Ubercart Stock to monitor individual components of a product?

Tags: 7, ubercart

For example, I'm selling Hamburgers.

Hamburgers require the following ingredients:

1. Bread
2. Beef
3. Tomato
4. Lettuce
5. Onions

For every one hamburger sold, stock decrement should be: 1 Bread, 1 Beef, 2 Tomatoes, 1 Lettuce, 3 Onions.

The ingredients will never be sold individually, they collectively make one product.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is. Make your hamburger a product kit which is made up of products, bread, beef, tomato, lettuce and onion. When you sell a hamburger Ubercart will be smart enough to control stock of the ingredients.